# How migrate existing SOAP endpoints to ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I've the good fortune of being able to kick off a new project with the tooling of my choice, which is ServiceStack. The Architecture is very solid and the product was out before web api was even a glimmer in someones eyes. That being said, it would be a great plus, if I could also recreate some legacy SOAP endpoints and route then through this service instead of have two apis running at the same time. Is there a preferred way to do such a thing?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about what migrating legacy SOAP endpoints over to ServiceStack entails.

But ServiceStack's [SOAP support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) works like all the other REST, Web and MQ endpoints and Content-Types, where it automatically exposes SOAP endpoints around your services Request and Response DTOs allowing it to be called via SOAP 1.1/1.2.

The inherent limitation in SOAP means that only Services that support POST (i.e. Post() or Any()) are available to be called by SOAP. For services that use any other HTTP/REST Verbs it will be disabled in the metadata pages as seen in the [SocialBootstrap API metdata pages](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/api/metadata). See [SOAP Limitations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#soap-limitations) for other things you should be weary of.

The [metadata pages](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/api/metadata) also contain links to your services WSDLs and XSDs, e.g:

- [/api/soap11/](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/api/soap11)
- [/api/soap12](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/api/soap12)
- XSDs: [/api/metadata?xsd=1](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/api/metadata?xsd=1)

If you want to host legacy .asmx SOAP services in the same application than you should [host ServiceStack on a /custompath](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#custompath) so you're able to use it with any other ASP.NET Web, MVC or other web services frameowrk.

Comment: Thanks Demis, I'll let the two services evolve independently.